# Can temporary character banality be lower than permanent?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

In Changeling the Dreaming, can a Changeling's temporary Banality be lower than its permanent? Or does it always starts from the permanent one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say that the book is not very clear in that, at least on the spanish translation.

Anyway, I understand that it can of course be lower. In fact, I haven't found a word of it starting at the same level as permanent one. **In fact** I haven't found a word of a what level it starts. The only reference I have found is the creation example, where again it's not mentioned, but you can see no temporary banality is marked on the character sheet, which would mean that it starts at zero.

If you reach a temporary banality of 10, you gain 1 dot of permanent banality. Again, it's not said, but seems logical that your banality resets to zero.

So, the book doesn't make a good job explaining it, but what I understand is that you can have temporary banality lesser, erqual or greater than permanent one.

Answer (score 4):

Banality is defined as one of the characters Tempers. Per page 150 of the second edition rulebook: "At character genesis, you assign the character's permanent Temper rating based on her seeming and any freebie points you spend in the Trait. *A character is then assumed to have a number of temporary Temper points equal to the number of permanent Temper points.*" (Emphasis mine.)

On the same page, it mentions that when you reach 10 temporary points of Banality, the temporary points are removed and you gain a permanent point of Banalty.

Comment: Could you check something while you look for page numbers? On my translation it says that temporary banality is what it's used to know how banal is a Changeling, and to calculate the effects of banality, but my logic says it should be permanent banality. If you find something, could you also post that?

Comment: It's page 152 in the second edition, and it's not mistranslated: the book says *temporary* banality causes you to slip into the Mists.  However, permanent Banality affects the difficulty of Enchanting, and cantrips are ambiguous.  (While not a mistranslation, I suspect it *is* an error, because I agree this seems silly.)

Comment: Tynam is right. The book says "The effect of Banality upon a character is measured by her temporary Banality rating." The ramifications of the Mists being based on temporary Banality and the above info about starting temporary Banality really ratchet up the difficulty level if the game. (I always love to find out I've been playing a game wrong for years.)